# Noop.js loaded from paypalobjects.com fails / very slow

Tags: performance, paypal

When analyzing the waterfall diagram via GTMetrix.com I noticed that my page loads the asset Noop.js very slowly (> 3 seconds) from https://www.paypalobjects.com/muse/noop.js and the status is even shown as "incomplete".

[image: GTMetrix.com Screenshot of broken asset]

Why does this happen? And what should I do to avoid this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No op means no operation, so apparently this is intentional. The referrer is an analytics package and it would seem this can be safely ignored.

It's asynchronous and doesn't affect anything else on the page.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Thank you! And how come that sometimes, when testing the same page, it gets completed very fast i.e. less than 300ms with status code 200 and sometimes this slow with the status (incomplete)?